# about python recursive import in python3 when using type annotation

Tags: python, python-3.x, forward-reference

**After spending another three hours, I thought I may got the solution.[forward-references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)**

**if there isn't any better way to do this, I'll close this question later and post that solution**

I'm doing reverse engineering on a program (and try to implement it using Python).

I got this problem

for example
I have a class in ComponentOfCar.py, the code is as follows

```
__all__ = ("ComponentOfCar");
import Car;
#...#imports other needed packages

class ComponentOfCar(object):
    def __init__(self, owner:Car.Car):
        self.owner = owner;
        self.type = "Default";
        #....#create other attribute
```

Another class like this(Car.py):

```
__all__ = ("Car");
import ComponentOfCar;
#...#imports other needed packages

class Car(object):
    __slots__ = ("m_lstComponents",....);
    def __init__(self, data:FlatBuffersBinaryData):
        self.m_lstComponents = list();
        self.LoadFromData(data);
        #....#create other attribute
    def InstallComponen(self, component:ComponentOfCar.ComponentOfCar)->bool:
        self.m_lstComponents.append(component);
        return True;
```

But after doing so I came across this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Y:\Car.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ComponentOfCar;
  File "Y:\ComponentOfCar.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Car;
  File "Y:\Car.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Car(object):
  File "Y:\Car.py", line 10, in Car
    def InstallComponen(self, component:ComponentOfCar.ComponentOfCar)->bool:
AttributeError: module 'ComponentOfCar' has no attribute 'ComponentOfCar'
```

The original program is written in a compiled language. Inside that the class inheritance is very complicated, and it has hundreds classes, Which makes me headache.

I want to make this process a bit clearer by using type annotations and seperate each class into individual files. But this would have to use recursive import.

After googleing for half day, I havn't find some solution, so I come here to seek help. Is Python cannot do this like compiled language, or I just make some mistake? I'm confused. How can I fix it.

Sorry about my broken English. And thanks for your time. :)

to be detailed

Here is the structure of the decompiled class declaration like this(it's c#, the whole file is about a hundred thousands of lines):

```
// Namespace: GameNamespace
public class Car
{
    // Fields
    protected List`1<ComponentOfCar> m_lstComponents; 
    public int ObjectID; 

    // Methods
    public void .ctor(Data data);
    public void AddComponent(ComponentOfCar c);
}

// Namespace: GameNamespace
public abstract class ComponentOfCar
{
    // Fields
    protected Car m_owner;

    // Properties
    public Car Owner { get; }

    // Methods
    public Car get_Owner();
    public void .ctor(Car owner);
}
```

Or my question is how to use python to implement this clearly.

Yes, in my thought the way to do this showed above, I know that it's wrong, but I have no idea about how to make it right.
I shouldn't separate them? Or I can have them written in another way (to avoid rescursive import and) to do the same thing as in c#?

Please tell me a way to solve this, thank you very much.

**After spending another three hours, I thought I may got the solution**

**[forward-references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) , I'm checking this. And if there isn't any better way to do this, I'll close this question later and post that solution, it may fixes my code.**

Comment: What I can understand from your code is that you are trying for circular imports which are not intialized. **Car imports ComponentOfCar and ComponentOfCar imports Car**. You may want to think again.

Comment: Thanks, I know that is wrong, but according the original code (which I decompiled from the executable) shows that relationship. Component OfCar has a pointer to its owner, and Car has a member contains sorts of components. Which I want to know is :is  python can't do this in this way ,or I make some mistake?

Comment: Which means I can write this relationship using another write way ,or I can't do this in anyway, that is my confusion. If I can't do that, I'm going to re-write  the relationship of the classes, but that makes more chaos.

Comment: You can do this in a better way in python. You may want to rewrite the code more clearly. Or give us some understanding of the object you required so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this would help,

component.py

```
class Component:
    def __init__(self, owner, data):
        self.owner = owner
        self.name = data['name']
```

car.py

```
from component import Component

class Car:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.components = []
        self.type = data['type']
        self.color = data['color']

    def add_car_components(self, data):
        self.components.append(Component(self, data));


c = Car({'type': 'bus', 'color': 'red'})
c.add_car_components({'name': 'frontdoor'})
c.add_car_components({'name': 'reardoor'})

for component in c.components:
    print(component.owner.type, component.owner.color, component.name)
```

Result:

```
->python car.py

bus red frontdoor
bus red reardoor
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both for your code and time.But I thought we may have different understanding of the c# code.Which is I think (the original executable binary) may use the 'm_owner' property (which is in a instance of ComponentOfCar) to find which car installed it.

Comment: Due to that, it's decompiled code shows the ComponentOfCar class have the property 'm_owner'; and when I go further into it, I actually find the assemble code did some thing like that (using that property to find it's owner) and I'm going to write that in python(because I want to .. emm .. write a python version of that program, so I want to have all the details remained. If I loose some information at here, I don't know it(that property) will be used or not, and if yes I need to fix that with another code).

Comment: You need to understand the Object Oriented structure of your case. Let me understand what object you wanna create and what are its characteristics?

Comment: In my code **Car** is a Object which has **Component** as a character of it. Try to Objectify what you are thinking or what your c# code is doing. If you do this, you will understand what to do with the Object.

Comment: I am not sure much about how c# works. But I surely know how object oriented programming works. I suggest you to understand it in Object way and then write it in Python way.

Comment: You can see in my code the **c <type: Car>** object is an entity. And it has type and color which are kind of components of the Car Object. And you can see that its initialized in the ComponentCar class itself.

Comment: The most important thing your code did't do is using type annotation to explain the function parameter, which is my original intention to ask this question, but my problem solved. And thank you for your precious time , code and, guidance. I'm closing this question. :)

Answer (score -1):

After some test, I finally got my solution. Perhaps it isn't the best way to do this (fix recursive import) but it fit my original thought.
which is said in this **[link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)**.

After some thinking, I thought this might be called forward-references, ad according to that doc link. I rewrite this two class as bellow:

ComponentOfCar.py:

```
__all__ = ("ComponentOfCar");
import Car;

class ComponentOfCar(object):
    __slots__=("owner","name");
    def __init__(self, owner:'Car.Car',prop:dict={"name":"NoName"}):
        self.owner = owner;
        self.name = prop["name"];

if __name__=="__main__":
  c=Car.Car({"type":"bus","color":"red"});
  door1=ComponentOfCar(c,{"name":"frontdoor"});
  door2=ComponentOfCar(c,{"name":"reardoor"});
  c.InstallComponent(door1);
  c.InstallComponent(door2);

  print("We got the car",c);
  for component in c.m_lstComponents:
    print(component.name,component.owner);

  comp1=c.m_lstComponents[0];#now we look at the first component
  print("the component %s was installed on a %s %s"%(str(comp1),
         comp1.owner.color,comp1.owner.type));
```

Car.py:

```
 __all__ = ("Car");
import ComponentOfCar;

class Car(object):
    __slots__ = ("m_lstComponents","type","color");
    def __init__(self, data:dict):
        self.m_lstComponents = list();
        self.type=data["type"];
        self.color=data["color"];

    def InstallComponent(self, component:'ComponentOfCar.ComponentOfCar')->bool:
        self.m_lstComponents.append(component);
        return True;
if __name__=="__main__":
  c=Car({"type":"bus","color":"red"});
  door1=ComponentOfCar.ComponentOfCar(c,{"name":"frontdoor"});
  door2=ComponentOfCar.ComponentOfCar(c,{"name":"reardoor"});
  c.InstallComponent(door1);
  c.InstallComponent(door2);

  print("We got the car",c);
  for component in c.m_lstComponents:
    print(component.name,component.owner);

  comp1=c.m_lstComponents[0];#now we look at the first component
  print("the component %s was installed on a %s %s"%(str(comp1),comp1.owner.color,comp1.owner.type));
```

And now, I can run this code correctly, and I got output like:

```
We got the car <__main__.Car object at 0x0000015904C6AAC8>
frontdoor <__main__.Car object at 0x0000015904C6AAC8>
reardoor <__main__.Car object at 0x0000015904C6AAC8>
the component <ComponentOfCar.ComponentOfCar object at 0x0000015904C647F0> was installed on a red bus
```

Now I can write python code strictly according to the assemble code. I can go on my work.

And if there is some better way to satisfy my need, please correct me.

Thanks for everyone. :)

Comment: I dont understand why semi colons there in your code.

Comment: Try writing in python way.

Comment: Is so non pythonic. In python we dont use CamelCasing.

Comment: Now check my code again. That is how it should be in python. Python follows a rule which is 'Keep it simple stupid' (KISS).

Comment: Thank you very much, using semi colons is my style, thus it may looks ugly, and I'm using that to identify which line was written by me and I had it checked in my mind. And I use CamelCasing just became I'm trying to fit the coding style in that decompiled c# file.Because **the most important point** I'm considering is to minimize the chaos.So I won't change the class name the member name and the function name.

Comment: If I changed anything, and made something wrong, I need to reference that c# file and assemble code to correct it, and after rewrite thousands of class definitions, I definitely will forget where I have changed the name( and another problem is some classes in that c# file inherented from Flatbuffers automatically generated was automatically re written to python by using regular expression. so in that 75classes, the property name, class name, function name are remains **exactly the same** as the original code), in that case who can help me?

Comment: At last, Thanks for your correction. In other code I don't use CamelCasing, but in these sorts of code, I think I'd better use the c# coding style to make the code at least looks like the original one.(I'm facing that file or ..emm.. doing reverse engineering on my own, I don't want to add to much new things or change to much, because I'm afraid I can't handle that much.)

Comment: You may not need to make it look like c# (original) code. Let it look like more python. I would strongly suggest go through this [PEP8 document](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).